# Вычисление бесконечной суммы с заданной точностью

Tags: c++, c, математика, ряды

Здравствуйте, при решении данной задачи возникли некоторые трудности. При вводе `х` ничего не происходит. Помогите, пожалуйста, ее исправить.

Используя рекуррентное соотношение вычислить сумму с точностью 10<sup>-6</sup>, `x` вводится с клавиатуры.

[image: задание]

Пример кода:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int n=0, k=0;
double eps=10e-6;
double s,x;
printf("vvedite x:");

scanf("%d%d, &n, &x");
for (k=0; k<=n; k++)
{
    s+=(factorial(2*k)+1)/pow((k+1), k )* pow(x, 4*k);
}

     cout << s << endl;
     system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, внимательно на эту строчку: `scanf("%d%d, &n, &x");`

Comment: А почему вы не применяете отладчик?

Comment: @VladD примерил - жмет в подмышках

Comment: @Igor: проклятая автозамена на телефоне!

Comment: @VladD, я бы не обратился на форум, если бы отладчик помог в решении проблемы..

Comment: @Anton: ну вы бы хотя бы указали, что показывает отладчик. Но это на будущее. Решение вашей проблемы — в первом комментарии.

Answer (score 2):

Может, стоит вынести переменные из строки?

Не `scanf("%d%d, &n, &x");`, а `scanf("%d%d", &n, &x);`?

Но это мелочи...

Еще - я бы не стал использовать все эти `pow` и факториал для каждого члена, а воспользовался бы тем, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но и это не главное. Только сейчас начинаются главные неприятности.

Вам задано вычисление с некоторой точностью, а не до некоторого члена (так что вы решаете по сути не ту задачу). Но сам ряд, как видно из приведенного соотношения, **расходящийся**. Так что задача оказывается, как бы выразиться мягко... некорректной.

Вы точно верно указали условие?